# Is there a specific way of referring new members to SE?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Do I get reputation points for it? is there a specific procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Once a site has been launched there isn't a way, nor is there any reputation for doing so.

If you refer someone during the Area 51 phase then there are badges and a 25 point reputation bonus for your Area 51 profile:

> Referred user with a confirmed email address follows through on their commitment  +25

[Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

You also get [Area 51 badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges) for referring other users:

- Activist (gold) Referred 100 committers to a proposal
- Campaigner (silver) Referred 25 committers to a proposal
- Lobbyist (bronze) First commitment referral
- Promoter (bronze) Referred 5 committers to a proposal